# Where can I find media button to drop my assets to the storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode10

I used to know where I could drop out my assets to the main.storyboard on the previous versions of X-Code, but I am now developing an App with X-Code 10 and I can not see that button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> for libraries or <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> for media, or select from the menu…

[image]

Comment: Weird. My Libraries submenu in Xcode 10 GM doesn't look at all like that.

Comment: Is your build 10A254a?

Comment: 10A254a, yes, that's it. Weird, eh? On mine, Open Library is the Option-key _alternate_ for Show Library. The fact that you are seeing both Show Library and Open Library at the same time suggests that something is serious wrong (with yours).

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot! That was the answer!! :D

Comment: I checked my key bindings, and I have something else set to `opt-shift-cmd-L` - removing that fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: All your key bindings are belong to us.